# Slow Query Execution on bigger SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a query that takes 14 seconds on my local machine, but 1:30 on a server with 8 cores and 64gb of ram.

I am running SQL Server 2008R2 developer on my local machine, and 64 bit Standard on the server.

I have isolated one portion of the query which appears to be causing the problem as when I take this out the query completes on both in under 10 seconds.

```
and (ID is null
     or (ID not in (select ID
                    from  Details
                    where (another_ID is not null)
                      and (yet_another_ID is not null))))
```

There are several other parts of the query very similar to this which don't seem to cause a problem.

The query plan shows as a percentage and is nearly the same on both servers.

Please help..

Comment: Use the execution plan to see if SQL Server has any recommendations to optimize the query. This is an easy first step. After that, review of the execution plan needs done. I will tell you that sub-selects are almost always slower performing than joins; based on what you posted, I think you should switch out that sub-select.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but my issue is with the difference in time between the 2 servers, not with the overall performance of the query. I know the query could be tidier but why the massive difference between servers?

Comment: Is the data size the same on both servers? The machines have different hardware? The machines have different processes running on them? Have you eliminated caching as a possibility? This is no longer a programming question and belongs on dba stack exchange site.

Comment: The 'larger' SQL Server could be running queries from thousands of users or have different data set, or different indexes, or different statistics, or fragmented/corrupt indexes, or...... etc. etc. etc.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. The larger server has barely any load on it at all and I am using exactly the same data set. When I used the execution planner on the Server and looked at missing indexes. There was a suggestion of an index that when applied increased the speed of the query to that quicker than my local machine (only 5 seconds). However, when I try looking at missing indexes on my local machine, the same index is not recommended. Can anyone please explain this?

Comment: You're still not giving enough information to be able to diagnose the problem. We have no clue about the structure of either of your systems.

Comment: it turns out that there was a large data import which had affected the query. Both data sets were not the same. The query still took 30 seconds on my local machine which is twice as fast as the server. I have added the suggested index which means the query now complete in 2 seconds locally and 4 seconds on the server. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First I would swap out the 'NOT IN' for a 'NOT EXISTS' which will probably boost performance overall and reduce your logical reads.

Second, when you mentioned that the dataset is the same size, did you mean that the dataset RETURNED is the same size, or that all of the tables you are accessing are the same size?  I ask because if tables you are joining to or using in a WHERE clause (e.g. Details in your example) are significantly larger this could cause performance problems too.

The last thing I would think of is the statistics could be stale.  If that is the case and you have a dedicated DBA, it would probably be a task for them.  If there is not a DBA available I'd start looking into how to refresh your stats.  One place to start is here:
https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/managing-sql-server-statistics/

I'm not affiliated in any way with that site or people on it, I have just found a lot of the content to be thorough, helpful, and geared toward teaching readers rather than spewing technical babble.

Would've left this in a comment, but rep isn't high enough :)